# Tmux panes out of order when creating in detached mode

Tags: tmux

When creating panes in detached mode like so

```
tmux new-session -d -s sessname
tmux splitw -v -p 30 -t sessname:1.0
tmux splitw -h -p 60 -t sessname:1.1
tmux splitw -h -p 30 -t sessname:1.0
```

The panes are out of order, and go like so when seen with `C-a q` (or `C-b q` for those with default prefixes):

```
1    |4
-------
2  |  3
```

Instead of the order I wanted, which would be

```
1    |2
-------
3  |  4
```

It took me forever to figure out why, so I'm posting the answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out tmux pane ordering is only reset to be in a standard order when calling `split-window` (alias `splitw`) on the *active* pane. Tmux pane numbers will default to creation order unless a new pane is split off from the current active pane, which will cause *all* tmux panes to have their numbers reset to the "correct" order.

All you have to do is call `select-pane` on the pane you're about to split just before your final `splitw` so that tmux knows to reset the pane numbering system:

```
tmux new-session -d -s sessname
tmux splitw -v -p 30 -t sessname:1.0
tmux splitw -h -p 60 -t sessname:1.1
tmux select-pane -t sessname:1.0
tmux splitw -h -p 30 -t sessname:1.0
```

here's what the "correct" order would look like if your major split is horizontal

```
1    |2
-------
3  |  4
```

or if you create your vertical splits first, the "correct" order would instead be

```
1  |  3
   |---  
---|  4
2  |
```